# How to display tooltip text for an unordered list element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I create an unordered lists, the text of each element is the name of a chapter. However, I would also like to provide the description of the chapter via tooltip text. My Javascript code to create a list element is:

```
var list_item = document.createElement('li');
var text_element = document.createTextNode(Object.values(json)[i].name);
list_item.appendChild(text_element);
```

I know that the title of an element is usually displayed as tooltip text, and I am mostly focusing on Chrome compatibility where that is the case. So I tried to add the title the same way I do for my buttons:

```
var list_item = document.createElement('li');
var text_element = document.createTextNode(Object.values(json)[i].name);
text_element.title = json[i].description;
list_item.appendChild(text_element);
```

However, this just displays the text in the list as normal, and hovering over the text does not cause a tooltip to appear. How do I get the description to appear as a tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Element.setAttribute(name, value);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) instead. For example:

```
var list_item = document.createElement('li');
var text_element = document.createTextNode(Object.values(json)[i].name);
list_item.setAttribute("title", json[i].description);
list_item.appendChild(text_element);
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for!